# During compilation, check that data members used in a function are also used in another function of the same class

Tags: c++, c++17

Need to fail the build if data members assigned in a function are not used in another function of the same class. For example, with the below definition, I would like to enforce that data members used in `setFunc` are also used in `compareFunc`.

```
class Room {
    public:
        double length;
        double breadth;
        double height;   

        double setFunc(){   
            //set values of length, breadth and height
        }

        double compareFunc(){   
            // compare current and previous values of all data members set in setFunc. 
        }
};
```

Disclaimer : I'm a newbie to c++ and build tools. I could not find an answer to this question anywhere, so created one here.

Comment: That's impossible. Why do you need that? What is your assignment? What requirements and limitations are there on your assignment?

Comment: This is a job for a test, not a build rule.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Need - There is a set function which sets values from user and there is a compare function which gets the list of all data members which could be changed by user. So, need to enforce that data members which are set in `set` function are also included in `compare` function.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using something else, like a *vector* of values? Then the "set" function can set the value, and the "compare" function can use all the values of the vector. With that said, there is still no way to enforce that the "compare" function uses all the value of the vector. The only way to "enforce" this rule is by documenting it and send the code for code-review to hopefully catch such problems. Or, as mentioned by @user207421, properly designed unit-testing.

Comment: I think you're asking the impossible. How could a compiler suite possibly check all variances and ensure your rules are applied at runtime?
Check if your required values are set within the function and handle any error cases.

Comment: Even if the compare function uses all variables, it could still use them *wrong*. So you have to write some tests anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no vector used here. The data members are mapped to fields in the UI.  By the way, appreciate your response.

Comment: Then, as mentioned, code-reviews and unit-testing. This isn't anything that the compiler can (or should) enforce.

Comment: How would you expect such a "check" to work, conceptually? If you have to specify the names of the variables that should be used, then the check itself can at least as easily become flawed as the computations it is supposed to check!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, unit testing is a possible way but even in unit testing a data member could be missed to include in that test right ? would you recommened static code analysis here. For example, can a python script be written to analyse all classes with `compareFunc` and make sure that data members set in `setFunc` are used in comparison in `compareFunc` ?

Comment: If the test knows the exact calculation that's required to use, and if it knows all the inputs, then it will know the exact result. If the "compare" function returns the wrong result then the calculation is wrong one way or another (perhaps used wrong operators, perhaps didn't use the correct variables, etc.) Either way, if the "compare" function uses the correct calculation and the correct variables in the correct way, the result should match. Of course test with multiple input values to make sure there's no false negatives.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will keep unit testing as a option. Also, I have updated my last comment asking about static code analysis to solve this requirement. Could you pls share your opinion ?

Comment: You don't want anything like `setFunc` in your code. It is a constructor's job to initialise an object.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are applying some analogous action in *exactly the same way* on *all of* the variables in question *then* you might `std::tie` them together and afterwards `std::apply` an appropriate function/functor/lambda to them, e.g.:

```
auto asTuple()
{
    return std::tie(length, breadth, height);
}
double setFunc()
{
    return std::apply
    (
        [](auto& t... values)
        {
            ( /* fold expression to assign appropriate value */ );
            // needs to include calculating appropriate return value!
        },
        asTuple()
    );
}

double compareFunc()
{
    // analogously...
}
```

Alternatively you can write your own kind of apply function that receives such function/functor/lambda, e.g.

```
template <typename F>
double apply(F&& f)
{
    f(length);
    f(breadth);
    f(height);

    // calculate return value while processing!
    return /* ... */;

    // alternatively you might return a tuple or an array of individual return values, if that helps you better calculate final result...
}

double setFunc()
{
    // maybe some pre-calculations
    auto r = apply
    (
        [](auto& t value)
        {
            // appropriate assignment
        }
    );
    // assuming array return value:
    for(auto d : r)
    {
        // calculate final result...
    }
}

double compareFunc()
{
    // analogously...
}
```

This latter approach allows you more flexibility in between how the analogies look like or to provide different functions/functors/lambdas to subgroups of variables, though with every new subgroup the whole matter gets more complicated...

Without such minimal analogy between the functions I don't see any other way how to achieve that.